# How to refresh the page and overwriting content?

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst

Testing on IBM Worklight with a HTTP adapter.

My question is: How to refresh the page and overwriting old with new set of list items? Or emptying the list items and add/append new list items?

1. Without page refresh concept,from drop down, if sport is selected the cnn sport news is appended then if technology is selected the cnn technology news is appended after the last list tag ended that is after sport news.
2. With page refresh concept (`window.location.reload();`). By trying the js code, the page refreshes but cannot append rss feeds item.

I want at a time one news category will be displayed and previous list will be overwritten.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RSSnew</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/RSSnew.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <!--application UI goes here-->
        <select size="2" id="cc">
        <option selected>select categories</option>
        <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type = "button" onclick="search()" value="Search">//onclick="reload(),search()"

    <ul id="news"></ul>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/RSSnew.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function search()
{
    window.location.reload();
    var a=$("#cc").val();
    alert(a);
     var invocationData={

             adapter:'cnn',
             procedure:'getStories',
             parameters:[a]
     };

     var options={
             onSuccess:su,
             onFailure:fa
     };
     WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}

function su(result)
{

    alert("success");
    var a=result.invocationResult.rss.channel.item.length;
    var i;

    for(i=0;i<=a;i++)
        {
            var b=result.invocationResult.rss.channel.item[i].title;
            var c=result.invocationResult.rss.channel.item[i].description;


            var d=$("#news");

            var e=$('<li><b><u>'+b+'</u></b></li>');
            var f=$('<li>').html(c);
            d.append(e,f);

        }
}

function fa()
{
    alert("failure");
}

function reload() {

    window.location.reload();
    //$("#news").remove();
//  search();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.location.reload();` simply empty the contents of the #news UL element.

In the `search()` function, replace the reload line with `ul.innerHTML = '';`. 
Should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery **setInterval** function method, you will refresh & overwrite your data without reloading page.

```
var doYourStuff = function () {
  // Your functionality 
};
setInterval(doYourStuff, 1000);
```

Comment: For the scenario mentioned in the question, this does not make sense. The user is looking to load content from *different* news categories - not from the same category as a "running news" so auto-loading seems inappropriate to me.